# too slow and sorting not work

Tags: c#, sorting, datagridview

I'm making `combobox` for sorting option on `datagridview`.

```
private DataClasses1DataContext db = new DataClasses1DataContext();
private int numberOfObjectsPerPage = 20;
private int CurrentPageIndex = 1;
private string ordering = "c.name ascending";

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    GetData(CurrentPageIndex);            
}

private void GetData(int page)
{
    page = page - 1;            

    var query = (from c in db.enterprise
    orderby ordering
                    select new { c.id, c.name, c.phone, c.email, c.type, c.city })
                    .Skip(numberOfObjectsPerPage * page).Take(numberOfObjectsPerPage);

    dataGridView1.DataSource = query;
}

private void orderBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (orderCB.SelectedIndex == 1)
    {
        ordering = "c.name descending";
    }
    else if (orderCB.SelectedIndex == 2)
    {
        ordering = "c.id ascending";
    }
    else if (orderCB.SelectedIndex == 3)
    {
        ordering = "c.id descending";
    }
    else
    {
        ordering = "c.name ascending";
    }

    GetData(CurrentPageIndex);            
}
```

I got two problem in here.

1. My current data is about `2.500` row. I'm using pagination so it will display `20` data/ page, but its still too slow when loading the `datagridview`. What could be wrong?
2. My Ordering button not work.

This is my first time using C#, so maybe I miss something in here :D

Update

So I changed my code as suggestion from the_joric

```
Func<IEnumerable<cooperations>, IEnumerable<cooperations>> ordering = t => t;
```

I change DBType to cooperations based on this reference (Hope I'm right :D)
[image]

But then my datagridview doesn't show anything, what I got is this

```
System.Linq.Enumerable+<TakeIterator>d__3a`1[<>f__AnonymousType0`7[System.Int32,System.String,System.String,System.String,System.String,System.String,System.String]]
A first chance exception of type 'System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
```

Comment: For the performance issue, you're still returning the entire 2500 rows to the client on each query.

Comment: I thought it work like limit and offset in MySQL :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your button doesn't work because you are sorting by constant string key. `orderby` is a syntatic sugar for `OrderBy<>()` method that should take key selector. In your case that selector is always a string that is the same for all items. But it should be a function that takes your object and returns its key

You may try something like that:

```
// instead of DbType your should use the type of db.enterprise
Func<IEnumerable<DbType>, IEnumerable<DbType>> ordering= t => t; // default ordering (as it is)
...
var query = (from c in ordering(db.enterprise)
                    select new { c.id, c.name, c.phone, c.email, c.type, c.city })
                    .Skip(numberOfObjectsPerPage * page).Take(numberOfObjectsPerPage);
...
// in your button click method
if (orderCB.SelectedIndex == 1)
{

    ordering = t => t.OrderByDescending(i => i.name); 
}
else if (orderCB.SelectedIndex == 2)
{
    ordering = t => t.OrderBy(i => i.id); 
}
...
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. But now I got exception (`System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException was unhandled`, Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection) on this line => `dataGridView1.Columns[0].Visible = false`

Comment: seems like you don't have columns in your grid